# Ubuntu Software Centre Problems

Tags: software-center

I'm new to Linux and I'm attempting to install stuff from the Ubuntu Software Centre, however, when I try it, it says "Failed to download repository information, check you're internet connection".

Any idea how to fix this?

Output - http://pastebin.com/eEAbEeD0

Comment: Can you open a terminal window, and enter the command `sudo apt-get update` and append any error messages to your question?

Comment: check you're internet connection" as suggested assuming there is no firewall blocking connections.. try updating from the terminal **(sudo apt-get update )** like @CharlesGreen suggested

Comment: I've added the sudo apt-get update output to my question.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using, and which release number?  The references which fail refer to version 11.10, which is severely depreciated.

Comment: Yep, I'm on 11, is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to `sudo apt-get update` in your terminal and look for any repositories that show `404` or `Unable to Fetch ...`

You'll then want to open your Software Sources and uncheck those corresponding lines.

If you still have `Unable to Fetch archives` then you should make sure your mirror is set to `Main Server` in your Software Sources.

To make sure it's fixed, when you run `sudo apt-get update` it should never say `404` or `Unable to Fetch ...`